# Is Dristhi (Evil Eye) Pottu,Photos and other activities are said in our scriptures?

Tags: practice, culture, superstitions

- Dristhi **pottu for new babies** are applied as a black dot in their cheek to escape from Evil Eye.
- **Industries have scary photos** in its gate as to escape from Evil eye .
- When a person looks **very jealously** or other bad emotions about the other persons **wealth,beauty,fame** is said to be an Evil eye.
- It is said that these evil eyes can cause Harm to the person by health,wealth,beauty or even accidents.

**QUESTION :**

- Is these practices to escape from Dristhi or evil eye is said in our scriputres ?
- Explain how can one man's look can cause the problem to others ?

Comment: The Atharva Veda has many mantras to protect one from many different evil afflictions and curses. There is no mention of an evil eye or protection from it in the Atharva.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda this is followed all over india isn't it so my opinion is there must be a scripture referring or else as you said even atharva veda doesn't consist it there may be chances for loss of scriptures containing it

Comment: it is a superstition that runs across cultures all across the world. It is not peculiar to India. Search 'evil eye' on wikipedia.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda yes friend i heard all religions use this but now i started bounty of 50 and have a answer with -2 down votes what should i do ?

Comment: if you want to withdraw the question you can ask a moderator to close without losing 50 points.