# Origin of evil eye

Tags: evil

Does evil eye have any religious origin or is it folklore?

Is it possible to meditate, accumulate power, and give someone the evil eye?

Will anything bad happen to you if you give someone else the evil eye?

Comment: What is evileye in the first place?

Comment: duplicate question.

Comment: It's some negative radiation, beam, which invades electromagnetic aura of one, just like how an wandering spacerock if comes within earth's orbit/spheres, stays inside earth's influence due to earth's gravity, unless its pushed out by much powerful bigger force(evil eye removal with salt, chilli etc). if one's not turiya, one can be affected by an evil eye, however turiya has ability to only positive, prana, so all negative get neutralised against turiya person.

Comment: This is a dup. of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17101/is-dristhi-evil-eye-pottu-photos-and-other-activities-are-said-in-our-scriptur