# Is there any pramana of 'evil eyes' existence in shastras?

Tags: astrology, tantra, agamas

People usually believe in casting a bad eye or evil eyes but is this believe authentic in the light of shastras ?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17101/is-dristhi-evil-eye-pottu-photos-and-other-activities-are-said-in-our-scriptur

Comment: @hanugm thanks for sharing